# Understanding django channels - QueryAuthMiddleware

Tags: django, authentication, channel

How to write custom authentication of user,  that connects to  chat over ws:// protocol? This user is on the other side of Django app, he is the mobile user, connecting websocket via ws:// from mobile app. I tried to test websocket with chrome extenshion, it couldn't connect to my websocket. I think it was because of authentication.

In Django channels docs it says:

> If you have a custom authentication scheme, you can write a custom middleware to parse the details and put a user object (or whatever other object you need) into your scope.Middleware is written as a callable that takes an ASGI application and wraps it to return another ASGI application. Most authentication can just be done on the scope, so all you need to do is override the initial constructor that takes a scope, rather than the event-running coroutine. 
>   Here’s a simple example of a middleware that just takes a user ID out of the query string and uses that:
>   The same principles can be applied to authenticate over non-HTTP protocols; for example, you might want to use someone’s chat username from a chat protocol to turn it into a user.

```
from django.db import close_old_connections

class QueryAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        # Store the ASGI application we were passed
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        # Look up user from query string (you should also do things like
        # check it's a valid user ID, or if scope["user"] is already populated)
        user = User.objects.get(id=int(scope["query_string"]))
        close_old_connections()
        # Return the inner application directly and let it run everything else
        return self.inner(dict(scope, user=user))
```

What query do I need to do? I don't know anything about that user, in fact its anonymous.

Help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

In this example code, you probably have to open the websocket connection with:

`ws://SERVER:PORT/PATH?1`

Everything after the `?` is the query string. In your example code, your query_string has to be a user id, so for example `1`.

You could change the code to use different query strings. For example you could use:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
from django.db import close_old_connections

class QueryAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        # Store the ASGI application we were passed
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        # Look up user from query string (you should also do things like
        # check it's a valid user ID, or if scope["user"] is already populated)

        query_string = parse_qs(self.scope['query_string'])
        if b'user_id' in query_string:
            user = User.objects.get(id=int(query_string[b'user_id'][0]))
            close_old_connections()
        else:
            user = AnonymousUser
        # Return the inner application directly and let it run everything else
        return self.inner(dict(scope, user=user))
```

Now, you can use this uri:

`ws://SERVER:PORT/PATH?user_id=1`

You sill have to make sure, that the user with the ID exists in the database. You also have to write actual auth code. Every user can connect to this application with a arbitrary user id. There is no password or auth-token required.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as well, did research a bit came across solution with the code snippet below:

let's say you have `User` class defined. You want authenticate user through query send query while establishing connection with ws.

I will pass channels installation and configuration let's say you have successfully installed channels and configured.

`QueryAuthMiddleware` class as shown below:

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.conf import LazySettings
from urllib import parse
from rest_socket.models import User
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
from urllib.parse import unquote, urlparse

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser

class QueryAuthMiddleware:
    """
    QueryAuthMiddleware authorization 
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        query_string = parse_qs(scope['query_string']) #Used for query string token url auth
        headers = dict(scope['headers']) #Used for headers token url auth

        print("query", query_string)
        if b'user' in query_string:
            try:
                user = query_string[b'user'][0].decode()
                print("user", user)
                existing = User.objects.filter(id=user).last()
                print(existing)
                if existing:
                    print("existinguser")
                    scope['user'] = existing

                else:
                    scope["user"]  ="no user found" 

            except User.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        return self.inner(scope)


QueryAuthMiddlewareStack = lambda inner: QueryAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

Your routing.py should be like this:

```
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import OriginValidator
from django.urls import path
import your_app.routing
from project.utils.auth import QueryAuthMiddlewareStack

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': QueryAuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            your_app.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Routing inside application:

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path("tasks/", consumers.Task)
]
```

and your ws connection to django-channels:

```
<script>
    var notification;

    if (location.protocol === 'https:') {
        notification = new WebSocket('wss://' + "window.location.host" + "/tasks"+ "/?user=id");

        console.log("with htpps")
    }
    else {
        notification = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host +  "/tasks"+ "/?userr=id");

        console.log("htpp")
    }

    notification.onopen = function open() {
        console.log('notification connection created for NotificationWebsocket.');
    };

    notification.onmessage = function message(event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log("Socket response from NotificationWebsocket => ", data);
    };

    if (notification.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        notification.onopen();
    }
</script>
```